# Database recreated everytime Application runs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Good day guys,

I noticed my application deletes database structure and re add new one everytime i Run my application.
The DBset uses DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges. I have read about the other options like CreateDatabaseIfNotExist. is there any other option to force it from recreating database?

And also with throwing any exception of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this by using Code First Migrations